# Android List Activity-Each row with different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listactivity, listadapter

I would like to create List Activity in Android where each row will contain different layout. For e.g. first row contains an edit text and a text view. Second row contains a button. Third row contains only an image.Thus, each row element as different layout.Please help me with this.

Comment: use custom adapter refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: AS rajeshwaran.t suggest custom adapter,but the row pattern is same for   all rows.

Comment: Yes I want different layout for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom adapter, and use a array of layout ids.
In adapter getView method:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

you can inflate different layout for different position value.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom `ListView`. In the `getView()` method, depending on the data being processed, inflate a different layout as required.

If you are using the `convertView`, I guess you might also want to set a tag to the views being returned from `getView()` to mark what type of layout it is using. When reusing, you can  check the tag, if its not the required type, then inflate a new one, etc.